# I've a 12 in my first page but I don't know why

Tags: debugging

I have a problem to solve because I read three time my code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother

\title{Rapport unité d'enseigement libre : ASTEP}
\author{ \&  \\\\\\Référent : }
\date{Vendredi 17 Janvier}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Unité d'Enseignement Libre : Engagement Social et Citoyen}
\subsection{Définition}
"L'engagment social et citoyen consiste en la aprticipation active à la vie sociale"\cite{ref1}. L'engagament social et citoyen est un pas en avant dans l'engagement d'un étudiant dans la vie de son environnement. Il y a plusieurs types d'engagement :
\begin{itemize} 
\item La participation à l'action de l'association de la Cordée de la Réussite 
\item Participation à l'action de l'association l'AFEV 
\item Participation à un projet : L'ASTEP ou PSPC (Partenaire scientifique pour la classe) avec l'association La Main à la pâte. 
\end{itemize}
\subsection{Objectif}
L'objectif de cette unité d'enseignement est l'apprentissage de capacités transversale que les cours habituels ne peuvent pas nous transmettre. Ce dispositif permet d'éduquer socialement l'étudiant. 
La pluralité de cet enseignement d'acquérir de nouveaux savoirs et maitrises : 
\begin{itemize}
\item La réalisation d'un projet sur le long terme
\item Appréhender la confrontation et l'expositino de soi
\item Percevoir les attentes du public concerné \cite{ref2}
\end{itemize}
\section{Partenaire Scientifique pour la classe}
\subsection{Définiton}
La création du dispositif Partenaire scientifique pour la Classe date de 1996, il vient du constat que les enseignants en école primaire sont majoritairement diplomé en lettre et que donc, l'enseignement des sciences est compliqué à mettre en place. 

De nos jours, ce dispositif met en relation des acteurs du monde scientifique, comme des scientifiques, des etudiants, pour une série de présentations sur un sujet que l'enseignant choisi. 
Pour nous étudiants, dans le cadre de notre unité d'enseignement: "Engagement Social et citoyen" et grace à l'association La Main à la Pâte, nous pouvons rentrer en contact avec des enseignants de primaire.
\subsection{But}
Ce projet permet un enrichissement trie parties. Dans un premier temps, l'élève éveille sa curiosité scientifique et ainsi, ouvre des possibilités de projets pour son avenir. Dasn un second temps, l'enseignant se met en confiance pour ses connaissances scientifiques, enfin pour l'étudiant il est confronté pour la première fois à une classe. 
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{triparties.png} 
\end{center}
\caption{Objectifs du partenariat\cite{ref3}}
\label{Objectifs du partenariat\cite{ref3}}
\end{figure}[t]
\section{Notre unité d'enseignement}
\subsection{Le choix}


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{Bibiliographie.bib}
\end{document}
```

but I didn't find the solution.

When I compile this code I have a 12 in my first page and I don't know why.

[image: Look at the 12 in the first page]

Comment: Do you get any error messages upon trying to compile your document? If so,which? Plese also don't ignore them. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: @JkLnS3 You should remove the names of other people from your sample document, this site is public! Click on “edit” to modify your post.

Comment: What is `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}
\makeatother` supposed to do? If you want your sections to be numbered with 1, 2, ... instead of 0.1, 0.2 (due to the missing chapter), why not simply switch from the `report` to `article` document class?

Comment: To expand on the correct answer below: for the difference between caption and label see for example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing#Pictures. As a label you usually choose a short, descriptive text, like `\label{objectifs}` or something. Also, a prefix can be used to indicate which kind of object you are labeling, for example `\label{fig:objectifs}` for figures, `sec:` for sections, `tab:` for tables etc.

Comment: @Marijn I agree, but one thing. Since the OP is using `\usepackage[french]{babel}` here, I would rather recommend `\label{fig-objectifs}` because when compiling with pdfTeX (or with TeX'82 according to `texdoc frenchb`), babel-french makes `:` an active character. The LaTeX kernel handles this well these days, but not `cleveref`, for one. Test with: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\label{sec:test}
Voir~\cref{sec:test}.
\end{document}`.  `:` isn't made active under LuaTeX or XeTeX → no such problem with them.

Answer (score 4):

If you put `\label{Objectifs du partenariat}` instead of `\label{Objectifs du partenariat\cite{ref3}}` it works.

**Explanation**

`\label{}` is only for later referencing. You can''t put `\cite{}` in there.